# Shell recognizes files in ~ but not in ~/Documents

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm taking a Unix class, and here's a part of my assignment:

For each file and subdirectory in the user’s ~/Documents directory, determine if the item is a file or directory, and display a message to that effect, using the file name in the statement.

So, what I have written is this:

```
docs=`ls ~/Documents`

for file in $docs ; do
    if [ -f $file ] ; then
        echo $file "is a file."
    elif [ -d $file ] ; then
        echo $file "is a directory."
    else
        echo $file "is not a file or directory."
    fi
done
```

My Documents directory includes these files and directories:

```
DocList.txt  (file)
Letter       (file)
mypasswdfile (file)
samples      (directory)
things       (directory)
touchfile    (file)
```

So I figured that the output should be this:

```
DocList.txt is a file.
Letter is a file.
mypasswdfile is a file.
samples is a directory.
things is a directory.
touchfile is a file.
```

However, this is the output:

```
DocList.txt is not a file or directory.
Letter is not a file or directory
mypasswdfile is not a file or directory
samples is not a file or directory
things is not a file or directory
touchfile is not a file or directory
```

I feel like I should mention that if I set the $docs variable to `ls ~' it will successfully display the contents of my home directory and whether the items are files or directories. This does not work with other paths I have tried.

Comment: You might need some quotes around those $file references if your user name has spaces in it.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the output of `ls ~/Documents` yet?

Comment: What about ~/Documents/?

Comment: My username is "alex", no spaces. The output of ls ~/Documents lists the contents with the normal files in white text, and the directories in blue text. I just tries ~/Documents/ and unfortunately, the output remained the same.

Comment: Hint: What directory are you running this script from?

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe So I had it in my home directory, but moved it to ~/Documents and it worked. Why is that? I can't run it from my home directory?

Comment: If your current directory is `~`, what do you see when you type `ls DocList.txt` ? Compare that to `ls ~/Documents/DocList.txt` . Now, consider that your script is doing the same thing.

Comment: @glenn jackman Ahhh I think I understand now. When I made the file variable in the for loop, I didn't specify the path, so it looked in the current directory?

Comment: Precisely. This is one of the downfalls of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You should do something like this instead: `for file in ~/Documents/*; do ...`

Comment: Well, that totally makes sense. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `ls` only outputs the file names without path.

So your `$file` gets the values

```
DocList.txt
Letter
mypasswdfile
samples
things
touchfile
```

from loop run to loop run.

If your current directory is NOT `~/Documents`, testing these file names is wrong, as this would search in the current directory and not in the intended one.

A much better way to accomplish your task is

```
for file in ~/Documents/* ; do
    ...
done
```

which will set `$file` to each of the full path names needed to find your file.

After doing so, it should work, but it is very error prone: once your path or one of your files starts having a space or other blank character in it, it will fall on your feet.

Putting `"` around variables which can potentially contain something with a space etc. is quite essential. There is almost no reason ever to use a variable without its surrounding `"`.

What is the difference here?

With `[ -f $file ]`, and `file='something with spaces'`, `[` is called with the arguments `-f`, `something`, `with`, `spaces` and `]`. This surely leads to wrong behaviour.

OTOH, with `[ -f "$file" ]`, and `file='something with spaces'`, `[` is called with the arguments `-f`, `something with spaces` and `]`.

So quoting is very essential in shell programming.

Of course, the same holds for `[ -d "$file" ]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `ls` command - you're treating the output of `ls` as absolute e.g. `/home/alex/Documents/DocList.txt`, but when you do `ls ~/Documents` it prints out `DocList.txt` (a relative file path / name).

To get the expected absolute behaviour you can use the `find` command instead:

```
docs=`find ~/Documents`
```

As mentioned in the comments and in another answer, to also be able to handle whitespace in filenames you need to do something like:

```
docs=( ~/Documents/* )
for f in "${docs[@]}"; do
    ...
```

Comment: No, use a bash array instead: `docs=( ~/Documents/* ); for file in "${docs[@]}"; do ...` -- anything else will not be able to handle files with whitespace.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. How will the for loop behave if there's a file named `hello world.txt` in ~/Documents/?

Comment: It worked fine this way though EDIT: You're right @glennjackman I added a file with a space in it and it interpreted it as 2 files and couldnt determine whether they were files or directories

Comment: @glennjackman - glglgl is saying OP doesn't have any spaces in their files. You are correct too though in that it's more robust to handle whitespace.

Comment: @glglgl, huh? Glenn is entirely correct: Scalar variables can contain any character other than NULs; UNIX paths can contain any character other than NUL; so you can only store one UNIX path per scalar variable if you want to be able to handle all the corner cases (filenames with spaces, filenames with newlines, etc etc). Hence, using arrays rather than scalars is correct here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but a simple `for file in ~/Documents/*` would work as well. While writing my comment, I wasn't aware that the OP uses `ls` - which is definitely wrong. But the OP as well uses variables the wrong way, what I wanted to comment about.